# ECDSA ECDH Man In The Middle Attack

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman

We have a long-term key used for signing/verifying the ephemeral keys. The problem is we have to first share the long term public key with the other party. Is it possible to avoid a man in the middle attack without using certificates? I will be using this for a TCP chat.

Comment: [Short Authentication String](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66222/18298) might be helping you if you have an audio channel.